# string manipulation A-B...-X-Y to Y-A-B-...-X

Tags: php, string

I have a string in this format:

Each substring is seperated by '-'

A-B-C...-X-Y

My question is how to move the last substring to the first as

Y-A-B-C...-X

in php

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is a *substring* one character or is it variable?

Comment: many characters, and not sure how many "-" in the whole string. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some code that'll do it:

```
// Split the string into an array
$letters = explode('-', 'A-B-C-X-Y');

// Pop off the last letter
$last_letter = array_pop($letters);

// Concatenate and rejoin the letters
$result = $last_letter . '-' . implode('-', $letters);
```

Comment: +1: Better than my version A with `array_unshift` -- I took the idea too far.

Comment: i wanted B-C...-X-Y-A, instead of my original post. so, i picked this answers. thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

### The cool kid way

Split the string with `explode`, move the last element of the resulting array in front, and glue it together once more:

```
$parts = explode('-', $str);
$last = array_pop($parts);
array_unshift($parts, $last);
$result = implode('-', $parts);
```

### The old school way (is also faster)

Find the last occurrence of the delimiter with `strrpos`, cut off a substring and prepend it:

```
$pos = strrpos($str, '-');
$result = substr($str, $pos + 1).'-'.substr($str, 0, $pos);
```

**[See both in action](http://ideone.com/RD7ep)**.

Comment: +1 for a string manipulation edit. Of course, like mine, this assumes the delimiter exists.

Answer (score 0):

For some Friday night craziness.

```
$last = substr($str, strrpos($str, '-'));
$str = strrev($last) . str_replace($last, '', $str);
```

***Disclaimer:** code assume that the delimiter always exists. Otherwise the result is `$str` reversed.*